# how to search inner array inside a json and return the same error with filtered data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of object and inside every array i have list of users, when i search i should be able to search the users and return value without effecting the existing structure.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yghfbw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I have tried but its not working have shared the stackblitz link where I have done

```
userList = [
    { state: 'KL', level: 1, USERS: ['jane', 'kete'] },
    { state: 'TN', level: 1, USERS: ['john', 'rock'] },
    { state: 'MH', level: 2, USERS: ['rahul', 'ricky'] },
    { state: 'AP', level: 2, USERS: ['ram', 'sham'] },
  ];

handleSearch(kete) // search us an input field detailed in stackblitz link
handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.userList = this.orgList;
    const user = this.searchFunction(this.userList, e.target.value);
    console.log(user);
  };

  // search function
  searchFunction = (arr, searchVal) => {
    return arr.map((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      const data = item.USERS.filter((user) =>
        user.toLowerCase()?.includes(searchVal?.toLowerCase())
      );
      return { ...item, data };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Do you want to filter the list shown in the UI or just want to find the matching object?

Comment: I think if you want to filter you should try tu use pipe instead of the input and filtering, cleaner solution IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are returning `data` in an object through `{ ...item, data }`, the retains all it's fields and adds a new field called `data` with filtered users.

Instead what you want to do is replace the list of `USERS` in the current `item` object.

```
  searchFunction = (arr, searchVal) => {
    return arr.map((item) => {
      const data = item.USERS.filter((user) =>
        user.toLowerCase()?.includes(searchVal?.toLowerCase())
      );
      return { ...item, USERS: data };
    });
  };
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3awup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()` and `includes()` to filter out the objects  where the username is in the `USERS` array of the object.

```js
const userList = [
  { state: 'KL', level: 1, USERS: ['jane', 'kete'] },
  { state: 'TN', level: 1, USERS: ['john', 'rock'] },
  { state: 'MH', level: 2, USERS: ['rahul', 'ricky'] },
  { state: 'AP', level: 2, USERS: ['ram', 'sham'] },
];
  
const findUser = (username, users) => {
  return users.filter(u => u.USERS.includes(username));
}

console.log(findUser("rahul", userList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1vi9e
Basicly, we make an array of users, and on each value of search input change, we search the array of users for any user whose name contains the search value and we're showing their names for testing purposes.